# Laravel helpers multiple calls different blade parts - Best Practices

Tags: php, laravel, helper

I create a helper to get the count of unread messages, and i'm calling that function on on a couple of blades
- Menu
- Profile Menu

That helper made a db query to get that value, currently when I'm outside the profile, we get only one query, but when I'm on the profile section, since we call 2 time that function I have 2 query's, one for each call, AND when i'm on the message list, we call 3 times!

What is the best way to proceed on this kind of situation? I try to search on internet some kind of best practices but I couldn't found anything.

Thanks in advance.
Pablo

EDIT:

Helper function

```
function unreadMessages()
{
    $messages = App\Message::select(['*', DB::Raw("IFNULL( `thread_id` , `id` )")])
        ->where(function ($query) {
            $query->where('receiver_id', Auth::user()->id)
                ->where('receiver_delete', false)
                ->where('receiver_read', false);
        })->get()
        ->unique(DB::Raw("IFNULL( `thread_id` , `id` )"));

    return count($messages);
}
```

Then i call that function a couple of times on different blades

Comment: You would need to elaborate your use case. Are these the number of unread messages specific to a user or some kind of global variable applicable on all users? Why do you have to call it twice or thrice? Post some code and elaborate on your app's use case. Then we can help you

Comment: add some code on the post, the unread message it's depends on how many unread message the user has!